Problem in ordering Citations in springer latex template
my document:
\documentclass[sn-basic,Numbered]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{url}

Based on data from the World Health Organization (WHO), approximately 16\% of the global population lives with a disability \cite{id1}.  Disability is a multifaceted and intricate human condition that significantly impacts the daily lives of those affected, restricting their mobility, senses, and cognitive and physical abilities. Within the scope of this article, we are focusing on individuals who have mobility difficulties, called paralyzed.

Medical conditions like paralysis severely limit movement. Typically, it is the result of a neurological injury. A stroke accounts for 29\% of all cases of paralysis, while spinal cord injuries account for 23\% and multiple sclerosis accounts for 17\% of all cases \cite{id2,id3}.

my bib file:
@misc{id1,
  title        = {Disability},
  url={https://www.who.int/health-topics/disability},
  note= {Accessed: 2023-10-07},
  author       = {World Health Organization},
 year={2022}
}

@article{id2,
  title={The design of an autonomous vehicle for the disabled},
  author={Madarasz, R and Heiny, Loren and Cromp, Robert and Mazur, Neal},
  journal={IEEE Journal on Robotics and Automation},
  volume={2},
  number={3},
  pages={117--126},
  year={1986},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@book{id3,
  title={Neurological disorders: public health challenges},
  author={World Health Organization},
  year={2006},
  publisher={World Health Organization}
}

They are not appearing as i have included in my document. for example [1] becomes [3].

only this code is used in the template for bibliography
\bibliography{sn-bibliography}

Based on data from the World Health Organization (WHO), approximately 16% of the global population lives with a disability \cite{id1}.  Disability is a multifaceted and intricate human condition that significantly impacts the daily lives of those affected, restricting their mobility, senses, and cognitive and physical abilities. Within the scope of this article, we are focusing on individuals who have mobility difficulties, called paralyzed.

there is begin document. i haven't put it here.
Citations are in the previous comment and also in the post

The sn-basic bibliography style is programmed to sort the bibliographic entries alphabetically by authors' surnames. If you're required to use this bibliography style, don't start messing around by disabling or otherwise overriding this sorting feature. The editorial staff of the journal or book that's going to contain your paper is not going to be pleased with your extracurricular activities.


The class uses sn-basic bib style, included in the zip, which numbers citations in alphabetic order of authors.
If you save the posted bib file as mybib.bib then running pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex on
this document produces the above output

% https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/18782940/data/v11
\documentclass[sn-basic,Numbered]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Based on data from the World Health Organization (WHO), approximately
16\% of the global population lives with a disability \cite{id1}.
Disability is a multifaceted and intricate human condition that
significantly impacts the daily lives of those affected, restricting
their mobility, senses, and cognitive and physical abilities. Within
the scope of this article, we are focusing on individuals who have
mobility difficulties, called paralyzed.

Medical conditions like paralysis severely limit movement. Typically,
it is the result of a neurological injury. A stroke accounts for 29\%
of all cases of paralysis, while spinal cord injuries account for 23\%
and multiple sclerosis accounts for 17\% of all cases \cite{id2,id3}.



\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}

springer zip file with latex and bibtex styles
